# Creating side by side table for longitudinal analysis in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a merged dataset that includes two longitudinal studies having recorded measurements from study1 and study2. I can provide an example as below:

```
data <- data.frame(
  weight_study1 = rnorm(100, mean = 60, sd = 5),  #numerical
  weight_study2 = rnorm(100, mean = 62, sd = 6),  #numerical
  gender_study1 = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE),  #categorical
  gender_study2 = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE)  #categorical
)
```

I want to create a table where I can have results from study1 one side and study2 to another side.
like adjacent to each other. How could it be done?

I have no idea how can I draw the table here in the post but just to give more context that what kind of table I am looking for is as follows:

```
Characteristics Pilot study 1 Pilot study 2 
Age             34(3)         67(8)
Gender          Male (40%)    Male(30%)
                Female (60%)  Female (70%)
```

Comment: If you update your question with an example of the output you want, it will make answering your question much easier. Also, please include any code you have trie so far. Thanks

Comment: No idea how can I show the output, but I am looking for a table lets say 

weight from study 1 is on left side and weight from study 2 on right side, I mean opposite to each other. 

About coding, I am trying very basics, summarising, and believe if I would not get any idea how can I do side by side table, I will create manually by calculating the values using basic code for mean and sd :)

Comment: Still not 100% on what you want but if you want to change the order of the columns you can either sort them into the correct order in your original df code and run it again, or use the function `select()` from the package `dplyr` e.g. `df %>% select(gender_study1, weight_study1, ...)`. You can also reorder columns in base R using column index e.g. `df[,3,1,4,2]` or whatever order you want them in.

Comment: Thanks for you kind response. I have added the table output (just learnt now how to do it). Please do check and let me know if my question is more clear now?

Comment: Nearly there. 1) There is no "age" column in your sample df, do you mean weight? 2) what are the values inside and outside the brackets in the "age" row representing? Average? Median?

Comment: Sorry for creating any confusion, I did mention age as a variable in the table because age is also one of the variables I will be using, just like weight. Row is representing - mean (sd) I mean for continuous variables it will be mean and sd and for categorical more like number of participants in each category and proportion.

Comment: Please update your question with all of this additional information, it'll mean your less likely to get downvoted and it makes it easier for others to find answers on this site. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not rollback useful edits, to include irrelevant clutter like "Any help would be highly appreciated" etc. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417887/why-was-my-question-edited-for-style/417889#417889

Answer (score 3):

On the surface, a solution to your question seems relatively straightforward. However, your data break the rules of [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). I encourage you to read the information in that link, particularly if you need to adapt this code in any way.

One way to produce your desired output is to first create a "tidy" version of your dataset. For the dataset in this example, that means converting (pivoting) your data into 'long' format, then back to 'wide' format. You have two groups of 100 (n=200) and three numeric variables worth of 'long' data. In other words, 100 rows becomes 600. Your desired output is further complicated by the fact that you want three different variables in a single column. I have added "age" columns to your sample data for completeness.

There will be more elegant ways to achieve this, and using a `for()` loop to populate an empty df would definitely require less code. But I was curious about a `tidyverse` solution. Based on the data you have provided, it works. It's inelegant because it would be quite clunky (not impossible) to edit if you want to include another variable for instance. But there is a lot of information on SO to help you achieve this if necessary. One further consideration, this has only been tested on study groups of equal length. Some modifications to the code that creates "df1" may be be required to accommodate groups of varying length. Again, SO is your friend.

Credit to @Mark for assistance with the `imap()` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77582266/return-values-from-multiple-columns-to-a-new-column-where-the-last-character-in)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# Generate sample data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(weight_study1 = rnorm(100, mean = 60, sd = 5),
                 weight_study2 = rnorm(100, mean = 62, sd = 6),
                 gender_study1 = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 gender_study2 = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 age1 = sample(18:65, 100, replace = TRUE), # Added column
                 age2 = sample(18:65, 100, replace = TRUE)) # Added column

# Step 1: get gender counts by study; 
#         get all numeric variables into a single column;
#         create "study" column and define study groups.
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(gender_study1) %>%
  mutate(count1 = n()) %>%
  group_by(gender_study2) %>%
  mutate(count2 = n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with(c("weight", "age", "count"))) %>%
  mutate(study = paste0("Pilot_study", str_sub(name, start = -1))) %>%
  ungroup()

# Step 2: use imap() to create a single (tidy) "gender" column;
#         select only necessary columns;
#         group by study and derive "age" and "count" strings for final output;
#         group by study and gender and derive "weight" strings for final output;
#         ungroup, select only necessary columns, and 'tidy' the "Category" names;
#         get distinct/unique rows, and pivot data to wide format.
df2 <- df1 %>%
  # If number at end of the gender column's name matches the end number of values
  # in "study" column, get the corresponding gender value
  mutate(gender = unlist(imap(study,
                              ~df1[.y,
                                   str_replace(.x, "Pilot_study", "gender_study")] %>%
                                ifelse(is.null(.), NA, .)))) %>%
  select(-starts_with("gender_")) %>% # Not "tidy" and no longer needed
  group_by(study) %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(str_detect(name, "age"),
                       paste0(round(mean(value), 1),
                              "(",
                              round(sd(value), 1),
                              ")"), NA),
         # Workaround needed to get count % per study because study group
         # count gets multiplied by the number of variables. n_distinct()
         # returns count of unqiue values
         temp = ifelse(str_detect(name, "count"),
                       paste0(as.integer(value),
                              "(",
                              round(100 / (n() / n_distinct(name)) * value , 1),
                              ")"), temp))  %>%
  group_by(study, gender) %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(str_detect(name, "weight"),
                       paste0(round(mean(value), 1),
                              "(",
                              round(sd(value), 1),
                              ")"), temp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  mutate(name = str_sub(name, end = -2),
         name = ifelse(str_detect(name, "weight"), "weight mean(sd)", name),
         name = ifelse(str_detect(name, "count"), "count(%)", name),
         gender = ifelse(name == "age", "", gender),
         name = ifelse(name == "age", "age mean(sd)", name)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = study,
              values_from = temp) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  rename(Category = "name")

df2
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Category       gender    Pilot_study1  Pilot_study2
  <chr>          <chr>     <chr>         <chr>       
1 age mean(sd)    ""        51.1(12.2)    50.9(12.1)  
2 count(%)        "Male"    55(55)        52(52)      
3 count(%)        "Female"  45(45)        48(48)      
4 weight mean(sd) "Male"    52.3(11.9)    51.2(12.2)  
5 weight mean(sd) "Female"  49.6(12.4)    50.5(12.1)
```

Comment: Tyrone, your kindness is truly appreciated. I'm grateful for your support. Indeed, my dataset has been somewhat challenging, especially with its complex column structure, making it difficult to compare study 1 and study 2. This complexity certainly taxed my brain, which might have affected the clarity of my questions. Nonetheless, I'm thankful for your patience. I'll give your suggestions a try tomorrow and will update you on the outcome.

Comment: You are very welcome. I meant to say, you can highlight the code from the start up to each %>% pipe (except the one inside the `imap()` function) and run the code step by step so you can see what each step does. For instance. `df2 <- df1 %>% ... -starts_with("gender_"))`, then `df2 <- df1 %>% ... ")"), temp))` and so on. Also, it is possible to nest the "count" `ifelse()` within the "age"  `ifelse()` statement but I've kept them separate to make the code easier to follow.